# Parsing serial port data

Tags: serial, c++, communication

Hello I found an Arduino project that works with serial port parsing and it had very interesting parsing code. I am trying to use it in my project but I still don't understand some lines and what is going there. (I marked them with ???).

```
char inData[82]; //create 82 char array
byte index = 0; //index byte (0 - 255)
String string_convert; //String
int PCdata[20]; //int array

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //init port
}

void loop() {
  parsing(); //loop the function
}

void parsing() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    //while there is data in serial buffer (128 bytes)
    char aChar = Serial.read(); //aChar - current symbol in buffer
    if (aChar != 'E') {
      //if aChar isnt the 'E' (End) symbol do:
      inData[index] = aChar;
      //(inData - array, index - loop № counter) write all Buffer to the array
      index++; //index + 1 - loop count
      inData[index] = '\0';
      //set the next position to '\0' or null symbol
    } else {
      //if aChar or current buffer symbol is 'E' (End) do:
      char *p = inData; //create inData address pointer
      char *str; //create pointer
      index = 0; //set counter to 0
      String value = ""; //create string
      while ((str = strtok_r(p, ";", &p)) != NULL) { //???
        string_convert = str; //???
        PCdata[index] = string_convert.toInt(); //???
        index++; //counter + 1 - loop count
      }
      index = 0; //counter to 0
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's parsing a bunch of semi-colon separated data, like "12;34;45;". In each iteration, it converts one value from character representation to its integer value.

`strtok_r` is the reentrant version of `strtok`. On Arduino you simply use `strtok`. Every time you have to parse a string having a list of values separated by some char, you use `strtok`.

## Name

strtok, strtok_r - extract tokens from strings

## Synopsis

```
#include <string.h>

char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);

char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr);
```

The strtok() function parses a string into a sequence of tokens (sub-strings). On the first call to strtok() the string to be parsed should be specified in `str`. In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, `str` should be NULL.

Each call to strtok() returns a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the next token. This token does not include the delimiting byte. If no more tokens are found, strtok() returns NULL.